# Jquery: Pegar height() ou width() não funciona com muitos elementos

Tags: jquery, height, carregamento

Tenho um catálogo que exibe mais de 400 produtos na mesma página (tem que ser assim) com duas setas mostrando a dimensão (altura e largura) que pega as medidas da imagem e aplica um CSS in-line com os mesmos valores, para as setas ficarem no mesmo tamanho da imagem. No Firefox todas setas pegam as medidas, mas no Chrome, os últimos produtos (pág. 64 e outras adiante) ficam com as setas pequenas, como se não tivessem pego os valores da imagem. Associei ao carregamento e apliquei um setTimeout() mas não funcionou mesmo alterando o delay para 20000, 30000 ou 0 tanto faz.

Url: http://noral.com.br/site/catalogo_noral

Cód:

```
setTimeout(function(){jQuery(".catalogo .container main .pag .pag-cont-padrao .item .box img").html(function(){
    var get_id_img = $(this).attr("title");
    var get_height_img = $(this).height();
    var get_width_img = $(this).width();
    jQuery(".catalogo .pag .item .dim-ver #dim-ver-"+get_id_img).css({ "height": +get_height_img+"px" });
    jQuery(".catalogo .pag .item #dim-hor-"+get_id_img).css({ "width": +get_width_img+"px", "min-width":"20px" });
}, 0)});
```